# ¿Como hacer para que el 3 en raya almacene la ultima jugada?

Tags: c

Me encontré con este problema haciendo el código de 3 en raya y al momento de jugar no me guarda las últimas jugadas.

El problema reside al momento de hacer la primer jugada al seleccionar el primer número es decir la primera jugada el juego directamente se finaliza y no me deja continuar y va directo a preguntar si quiero jugar de nuevo o no.

---

Adjunto el código del juego:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>



int main(){

    char j1[50];
    char j2[50];
    char numerost[2][2];
    char a,f1,f2;

    int i,j,fpre1,fpre2,lugar,n,aux;

do{

    {   //jugadores(hecho)

    system("cls");
    printf("bienvenidoa Tres en Raya.\n");
    printf("Presione una tecla para comenzar.\n");

    getch();
    system("cls");

    printf("Indique nombre del jugador 1:");
    //gets(j1);
    scanf("%s",&j1);
    fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");

    printf("Indique nombre del jugador 2:");
    //gets(j2);
    scanf("%s",&j2);
    fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");

    }
    {   //eleccion ficha jugadores (hecho)
    {//jugador 1
    do{

        printf("%s,elija ficha con la que jugar.\n",j1);

        printf("1.X.\n");
        printf("2.O.\n");
        printf("3.€.\n");
        printf("4.$.\n");
        printf("5.@.\n");

            scanf("%d",&fpre1);
            fflush(stdin);

        switch(fpre1){


            case 1:
                f1='X';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 2:
                f1='O';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 3:
                f1='€';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 4:
                f1='$';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 5:
                f1='@';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;


            default: printf("introduzca un numero valido");
                break;
    }
}
    while(0>fpre1||fpre1>5);

    printf("%s jugara con %c\n\n",j1,f1);}

    {//jugador 2

    do{
        printf("%s,elija ficha con la que jugar.\n",j2);

        printf("1.X.\n");
        printf("2.O.\n");
        printf("3.€.\n");
        printf("4.$.\n");
        printf("5.@.\n");

            scanf("%d",&fpre2);
            fflush(stdin);



        switch(fpre2){

            case 1:
                f2='X';

                break;

            case 2:
                f2='O';

                break;

            case 3:
                f2='€';

                break;

            case 4:
                f2='$';

                break;

            case 5:
                f2='@';

                break;

            default: 
            printf("introduzca un numero valido\n");
                break;
        }
        if(fpre1==fpre2){
                printf("las fichas no pueden ser iguales.\n\n");
            }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    } 
    while(fpre1==fpre2||0>fpre2||fpre2>5);

    printf("%s jugara con %c\n\n",j2,f2);}




    }
    {   //tablero(hecho)
    {   //numeros tablero(hecho)
    a='1';
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                numerost[i][j]=a++;
            }
        }   
    }
    {   //tablero estructura(hecho)
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                if(j<2){

                printf(" %c|",numerost[i][j]);
                }

                else{
                    printf(" %c",numerost[i][j]);
                }

        }
        if(i<2){
        printf("\n---------");
        printf("\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("\n");
        }   
            }

    }
    }
    {   //colocacion de fichas 

    do{

        printf("Coloca la ficha.\n");
        scanf("%d",&aux);
        fflush(stdin);

    }while(aux<1||aux>9);


        switch(aux){
            case'1':
                i=0;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                break;  
            case'2':
                i=0;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'3':
                i=0;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;  
            case'4':
                i=1;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'5':
                i=1;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'6':
                i=1;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'7':
                i=2;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'8':
                i=2;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }       
                    break;
            case'9':
                i=2;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;      

        }
        numerost[i][j]=f1;

        {   //tablero(hecho)
    {   //numeros tablero(hecho)
    a='1';
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                numerost[i][j]=a++;
            }
        }   
    }
    {   //tablero estructura(hecho)
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                if(j<2){

                printf(" %c|",numerost[i][j]);
                }

                else{
                    printf(" %c",numerost[i][j]);
                }

        }
        if(i<2){
        printf("\n---------");
        printf("\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("\n");
        }   
            }

    }
    }       








    }
    {   //jugar otra vez
    printf("¿desea volver a jugar?\n");
    printf("1.Si.\n");
    printf("2.No.\n");`introducir el código aquí`
    scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    }while(n==1); 
}
```

Comment: ¿ Las 300 líneas son necesarias para reproducir tu problema ? ¿ No has podido **aislarlo** ni un poco siquiera ? ¿ La parte de introducir los nombres y seleccionar ficha es imprescindible ? ¿ La parte de la lógica de los movimientos también ? Deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Debo admitir que cometí un error, no es necesaria la librería `string.h` logré hacer que tu código funcionara sin ella, tenías una infinidad de errores de escritura, y recuerda que para asignar un carácter debes manejarlo como cadena, por lo tanto, la variable a la que lo asignes debe ser un `array` es posible que le falten algunos detalles que no puedo percibir desde mi celular, pero acá te lo dejo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>



int main(){

    char j1[50];
    char j2[50];
    char numerost[2][2];
    char a[1],f1[1],f2[1];

    int i,j,fpre1,fpre2,lugar,n,aux;

do{

    {   //jugadores(hecho)

    system("cls");
    printf("bienvenido a Tres en Raya.\n");
    printf("Presione una tecla para comenzar.\n");

    getch();
    system("cls");

    printf("Indique nombre del jugador 1:");
    //gets(j1);
    scanf("%s", j1);
    fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");

    printf("\nIndique nombre del jugador 2:");
    //gets(j2);
    scanf("%s", j2);
    fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");

    }
    {   //eleccion ficha jugadores (hecho)
    {//jugador 1
    do{

        printf("\n%s,elija ficha con la que jugar.\n",j1);

        printf("1.X.\n");
        printf("2.O.\n");
        printf("3.&.\n");
        printf("4.$.\n");
        printf("5.@.\n");

            scanf("%d",&fpre1);
            fflush(stdin);

        switch(fpre1){


            case 1:
                f1[1]='X';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 2:
                f1[1]='O';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 3:
                f1[1]='&';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 4:
                f1[1]='$';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 5:
                f1[1]='@';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;


            default: printf("introduzca un numero valido");
                break;
    }
}
    while(0>fpre1||fpre1>5);

    printf("%s jugara con %c\n\n",j1,f1[1]);}

    {//jugador 2

    do{
        printf("%s,elija ficha con la que jugar.\n",j2);

        printf("1.X.\n");
        printf("2.O.\n");
        printf("3.&.\n");
        printf("4.$.\n");
        printf("5.@.\n");

            scanf("%d",&fpre2);
            fflush(stdin);



        switch(fpre2){

            case 1:
                f2[1]='X';

                break;

            case 2:
                f2[1]='O';

                break;

            case 3:
                f2[1]='&';

                break;

            case 4:
                f2[1]='$';

                break;

            case 5:
                f2[1]='@';

                break;

            default: 
            printf("introduzca un numero valido\n");
                break;
        }
        if(fpre1==fpre2){
                printf("las fichas no pueden ser iguales.\n\n");
            }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    } 
    while(fpre1==fpre2||0>fpre2||fpre2>5);

    printf("%s jugara con %c\n\n",j2,f2[1]);}




    }
    {   //tablero(hecho)
    {   //numeros tablero(hecho)
    a[1]='1';
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                numerost[i][j]=a[i];
            }
        }   
    }
    {   //tablero estructura(hecho)
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                if(j<2){

                printf(" %c|",numerost[i][j]);
                }

                else{
                    printf(" %c",numerost[i][j]);
                }

        }
        if(i<2){
        printf("\n---------");
        printf("\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("\n");
        }   
            }

    }
    }
    {   //colocacion de fichas 

    do{

        printf("Coloca la ficha.\n");
        scanf("%d",&aux);
        fflush(stdin);

    }while(aux<1||aux>9);


        switch(aux){
            case 1:
                i=0;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                break;  
            case 2:
                i=0;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case 3:
                i=0;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;  
            case 4:
                i=1;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case 5:
                i=1;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case 6:
                i=1;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case 7:
                i=2;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case 8:
                i=2;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }       
                    break;
            case 9:
                i=2;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1[1]||numerost[i][j]==f2[1]){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;      

        }
        numerost[i][j]=f1[1];

        {   //tablero(hecho)
    {   //numeros tablero(hecho)
    a[1]= '1';
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                numerost[i][j]=a[i];
            }
        }   
    }
    {   //tablero estructura(hecho)
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                if(j<2){

                printf(" %c|",numerost[i][j]);
                }

                else{
                    printf(" %c",numerost[i][j]);
                }

        }
        if(i<2){
        printf("\n---------");
        printf("\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("\n");
        }   
            }

    }
    }       








    }
    {   //jugar otra vez
    printf("¿desea volver a jugar?\n");
    printf("1.Si.\n");
    printf("2.No.\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    }while(n==1); 
}
```